# Mobile device in Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

Have the problem. Need to append the  to another element on the page, but in my case, i can't append  to elements (except tag ). This is my code for mobile (it works, but i don't need `var textnodes = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];` i need something like this: `var textnodes = document.getElementsByClassName('some-custom-class-name')[0];`):

```
if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
      document.getElementById('class-mobile').style.display = 'block';
      var nodes = document.getElementById("class-mobile");
      var textnodes = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
      textnodes.appendChild(nodes);
}else{
  document.getElementById('class-button').style.display = 'block';
      var node = document.getElementById("class-button");
      var textnode = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
      textnode.appendChild(node);
```

}
With desktop  i have 0 problem. But is this code the only way to append my custom button to the page using GTM?